# Template strings with UTF8 in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-templates

Please I need help with python 2.7.
I use `from string import Template`
and there error with Unicode
if I print the string without Template working good
and if I print it under Template appear error

```
AH01215: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

my example: 2 files:

- index.py
- template.py

in `template.py` I use this code

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
########################################################
#
from string import Template
ABC = Template("""<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
Hello ${NAME}""")
```

and in `index.py` I use this code

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
########################################################
import template
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
ZXC = "m’a réveillé"
print template.ABC.substitute(dict(NAME=ZXC))
```

If I used this code appear the error above
and if I print it direct without under template `print ZXC` working good

How can fix this utf8 under the template?

Comment: Hi, try this: `ZXC = u"m’a réveillé".encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')`

Answer (score 1):

It is needed to escape the special chars before feeding the template with them.
But first specify that the string is unicode. I believe your `index.py` should just become:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
########################################################
import template
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
ZXC = u"m’a réveillé".encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
print template.ABC.substitute(dict(NAME=ZXC))
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, i find the issue in sql results must be add .encode('UTF-8') in it also